# how to install express js on ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I installed nodejs as mentioned [here](http://slopjong.de/2012/10/31/how-to-install-the-latest-nodejs-in-ubuntu/), and then I installed express by running `sudo npm install -g express@3`  it got installed but when I try to create an app or even try to look at the version by running `express -v` or `express -V` it doesn't give any sort of output.

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried following the guide on the express website? http://expressjs.com/guide.html

Comment: What about just 'express'? Does that start the site creation process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installation of node in ubuntu is fairly a straight forward process. I don't know what gone wrong with your earlier attempt.anyway you can install it again if you wish. there are two ways to install node.

1. Download and install from nodejs.or
2. Use NVM(node version manager)

I always prefer the NVM method because it not only allows you to switch between versions but also avoids some of issues that otherwise you may face later. example, can't install npm packages globally without sudo.

Before you start remove your old installation

```
sudo rm -r ~/.npm
```

Now install nvm

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.16.1/install.sh | bash
```

To activate nvm

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Then install node

```
nvm install 0.10
nvm use 0.10
```

To set a default Node version to be used in any new shell

```
nvm alias default 0.10
```

Check everything done properly

```
node --version
```

Then install express

```
npm install -g express
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I got this `=> Downloading nvm from git to '/usr/sbin'
=> fatal: destination path '/usr/sbin' already exists and is not an empty directory.
`

Comment: Try this command `unset NVM_DIR` and then try the install script again

Comment: `anvesh@ubuntu:~$ express -v
The program 'express' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install node-express
`

Comment: I just had to link the expressjs to run globally. It worked, Thank you for your help. One last question do I have to activate nvm each time I'm working on nodejs like **virtualenv** for python?

Comment: no. you don't have to activate nvm each time. the paths are already set by the script itself and we set alias so that each time we don't have to run `nvm use 0.10`